# Load Google Calendar Events periodically

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

Im currently working on a SmartMirror Project using a php Page. I'm trying to get my upcoming Google Calendar events using js and oauth 2.0. So far everythings working fine. With the Sample from [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) I get my upcoming events when I load the page. The function checkAuth ist called onload.

I want the Eventlist to be up-to-date without refreshing the page. How can I accomplish that? Which function do i have to call in specific intervals?

I'm quite new to JS so thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well it actually works now. I just call loadCalendarApi() at the onload event. The call via setTimeout() is doing my interval-job.

Stupid question - easy answer.